# Strange error in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery ajax to fetch the results from a file according to the data selected from a select box and the idea is to call the ajax everytime the select box value changes as shown below.

HTML FORM:

```
<tr>
<td>Match : </td><td><select class="select" id="selmatch">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Match</option>
.....
</select></td></tr>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

alert('here');

$('#selmatch').on('change',function(){
    alert('h1');
    var id=$(this).val();
    var datastring="id="+id;

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"innchange.php",
        data:datastring,
        cache:false,

        success:function(data)
        {
            alert('h2');
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Now the problem is that the jquery code itself is not getting called.i.e i am not getting the first `alert('here')` message itself.i have checked that jquery is working for other tasks and i am also able to simply hide a element on the same page just for checking but with this function,it is not working.

Note that i have kept this code in body section and even on keeping it in the head section the problem persists.Any help as to where the problem lies?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no error just the function itself is not executed.

Comment: Have you correctly linked to the jQuery library and done it before this piece of code?

Comment: try `$(function () { });`

Comment: What if you remove all code except the alert call inside the ready handler?

Comment: Make sure you've added jQuery js reference file and try with<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

Comment: @No1_Melman it worked like a charm but what was the reason for the problem can u please explain.

Comment: @Ankur unfortunately there is no reason for why it works, there might be a subtle change or coding something that means this one works. But there is no difference in the implementation

Answer (score 0):

It's working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Kvk22/

Make sure:

1. You have no errors in the console
2. You have correctly included jQuery
3. Include scripts with type="text/javascript"

Demo code:

HTML:

```
<select class="select" id="selmatch">
    <option selected="selected" value="0" disabled>Select Match...</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Match 1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Match 2</option>    
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    alert('here'); // gets executed

    $('#selmatch').on('change',function(){
        alert('Changed'); // gets executed
    });

});
```

Comment: i had another script in the head section starting with $(document)....
so on using $(function{...it works...